# Generate chart as an html file with custom name

Tags: r, googlevis

I like to create bunch of googleVis charts and one I create the charts, I like to create a different html files with custom names so that I can reference them in my front page with divs.

For example, I am doing this:

```
x <- gvisTable(mtcars)
writeLines(x, "cars.html")
```

I get this error:

> Error in writeLines(x, "cars.html") : invalid 'text' argument

Ideas how would I address this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer, I can simply to this and write it to any html file I like:

```
cat(x$html$chart, file="tmp.html")
```